# Beamer: use Frankfurt theme blocks with default theme

Tags: beamer, presentations

I'm using the default Beamer theme because I like how it looks with the beaver color theme. However, the only thing I don't like about it is that blocks do not have a box around them. I like the block style from the Frankfurt theme, but I don't quite want to use the whole Frankfurt theme as it changes some things I like about the default theme.

Is there any way I could use the Frankfurt theme for just blocks, and keep using the default theme for everything else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the blocks in the same colour as with Frankfurt, you could use the `orchid` colour theme in addition.

If the blocks should also have the same shape, add `\useinnertheme{rounded}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{title}
    content...
    \end{block}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I wasn't aware you could use two color themes together.