# How to get the block style of boadilla theme in other beamer themes

Tags: beamer

I want the block style of Boadilla theme with default theme. I came across this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426726/142880), which helped me. But I want to further customise the boxes, like I want to give border to the blocks.
Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=red!20!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=red, bg=red!40!white}
% \definecolor{bitsdeepBlue}{RGB}{42, 42, 134}

\newtcolorbox{resp}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,%
    colback=red!20!white!90!,%
    colframe=red!85!white!90!,%
    colbacktitle=red!45!white!90!,
    % size=small,%
    % boxrule=1pt,%
    title=\textbf{\textit{Example}},%
    halign title=flush left,%
    coltitle=red,%
    breakable,%
    drop fuzzy shadow=black!70!white,%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{example}
    this is default.
    \end{example}
    \begin{resp}
    this is what I am able to get
    \end{resp}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This give me [image: as below] but the block is little smaller, also the shadow is not as the same. Even I don't want border in the title-body mixing place. Just the outer border would have been fine. Also the block title is not left-justified fully.

Anyone help me with that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- you can move the title (and content) further left with `left=0pt`
- to remove the rule between the title and the body: `titlerule=0pt`
- to adjust the height `top=1pt` and `bottom=0pt`
- to get the same width of the block: `enlarge left by=-0.1cm` and `grow to right by=0.21cm`

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=red!20!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=red, bg=red!40!white}
% \definecolor{bitsdeepBlue}{RGB}{42, 42, 134}

\newtcolorbox{resp}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,%
    colback=red!20!white!90!,%
    colframe=red!85!white!90!,%
    colbacktitle=red!45!white!90!,
    % size=small,%
    % boxrule=1pt,%
    title=\textbf{\textit{Example}},%
    halign title=flush left,%
    coltitle=red,%
    breakable,%
    drop fuzzy shadow=black!70!white,%
    left=0pt,
    titlerule=0pt,
    top=1pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    enlarge left by=-0.1cm,
    grow to right by=0.21cm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{example}
    this is default.
    \end{example}
    \begin{resp}
    this is what I am able to get
    \end{resp}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox ), it is now much easier to replicate the look and feel of beamer blocks with tcolorboxes:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=red!20!white, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=red, bg=red!40!white}

\useinnertheme[shadow,rounded]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
 boxrule=1pt,
 frame style={draw,red!85!white}
}
   
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{example}
    this is default.
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]