# Beamer block cream color

Tags: beamer, color, block

reading a presentation I found a block with this color combination (image attached)
[image]

Can someone guide me on how to get a block with these colors?

Comment: This looks like a tcolorbox, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628683/how-to-get-the-block-style-of-boadilla-theme-in-other-beamer-themes/652047#652047 for an example of using them in beamet

Comment: According to the eyedropper in Firefox's web developer tools on my computer, the cream color in the JPEG you posted is #FFFFDD. I'm not using beamer yet, but I think, after  converting to decimal, the color could be defined `\definecolor{coolcream}{RGB}{255,255,221}` and then used for block backgrounds with `\setbeamercolor{block}{bg=coolcream}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a `tcolorbox` more than a `beamer` block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{cream}{RGB}{255,255,221}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cream, title=Definition, colbacktitle=black!15, coltitle=black]
\begin{align*}
\beta^+(u) & =\limsup_{y\rightarrow\infty} \max_{(a_p)}\left(\left|[0,y]\in S_{y^{1/u}}\right|\frac{\log(y^{1/u})}{e^{-\gamma}y}\right),\\
\beta^-(u) & =\liminf_{y\rightarrow\infty} \max_{(a_p)}\left(\left|[0,y]\in S_{y^{1/u}}\right|\frac{\log(y^{1/u})}{e^{-\gamma}y}\right).\\
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]